# Java intercept command prompt reply

Tags: java, command, cmd, prompt, reply

I was doing some cmd commands via java that are only input in the command prompt.
I was wondering if there was a way to programatically fetch and reply to a command prompt question via Java?

e.g.: I add a remote GIT repository to my GIT structure locally, so when I execute:

```
$ git remote add [url],
```

I get prompted for a password. Can i catch this message (for example to pass the message to the user) AND reply in the same command prompt programming object/cmd window.

(the AND is explicitly in there because it would be useless to execute above command, read prompt reply, close command prompt, send password via a new cmd command in a new and thus non-related new prompt window).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are executing the command using Runtime.getRuntime().exec, capture/monitor the sub process's input stream and write to the output stream to send message to it.

E.g

```
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Command ");        
    OutputStream pout = process.getOutputStream();
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(pout);
    pw.println("Command response here");
```

Comment: So the response I get is indeed 'Password:', How can I reply my password again to the cmd prompt so that the authentiation is done? Thx for your answer in advance!

Comment: You might be getting 'Password:' from output stream (pout) right? then  to send the password, try "pw.println("mypassword");"

Answer (score 0):

YOu can interact with the standard input / output / error streams of another command by using a [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to start that command as a [`Process`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html). In that case, the process usually won't directly talk to a command window, so you'll have to print its output to the user if that is needed.

Note that some processes take particular care *not* to read passwords from standard input, but from the console window instead. In that case, the above might not work. Usually commands do provide some means to specify a different source for passwords. In the case of `git`, please search for the `GIT_ASKPASS` environment variable as well as the `core.askpass` configuration setting.